# read files from in Android internal storage using delphi

Tags: android, delphi, storage, internal

is it possible to read file.db from internal storage in android /data/data/.... 
using android firemonkey app using delphi not java?, i tried opening files from internal storage but access was denied even my devise is Rooted !
any help will be appreciated. many thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to access the internal storage for your own app, or someone else's app? If someone else's, you don't have access unless that app specifically grants access.

Comment: from my own app, in other words, i need to open the file or read it in my app

Comment: I meant, are you trying to have your app access its own internal storage, or are you trying to have your app access another app's internal storage?  An app has full access to its own internal storage, but must be granted access to another app's internal storage. Please show the actual code you are having trouble with, and also indicate which version of Delphi you are using.

Comment: im trying to access another app internal files from my app, Delphi xe6, access is denied when i tried to copy the file or open it.

Comment: Again, your app *does not* have access to another app's internal storage files, unless that app explicitly grants access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files stored in Internal storage are private to the app that creates them. Your app cannot access another app's internal storage files unless that app explicitly grants access when it creates them. This is clearly stated in the Android documentation:

[Using the Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

> By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and **other applications cannot access them** (nor can the user).

When an app creates a file in internal storage (using [`Context.openFileOutput()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)), it choose whether to use [`MODE_PRIVATE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE) permission:

> the default mode, where the created file can only be accessed by the calling application (or all applications sharing the same user ID).

Or whether to enable [`MODE_WORLD_READABLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) and/or [`MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE) permissions:

> allow all other applications to have read access to the created file.

> allow all other applications to have write access to the created file.

Without those permissions, your app *WILL NOT HAVE ACCESS* to the other app's files.  Also note that these permissions were **deprecated in API level 17**:

> Creating world-(readable|writable) files is very dangerous, and likely to cause security holes in applications. It is strongly discouraged; instead, applications should use more formal mechanism for interactions such as ContentProvider, BroadcastReceiver, and Service. There are no guarantees that this access mode will remain on a file, such as when it goes through a backup and restore.